# is this possible convert current page to AMP

Tags: magento, amp-html, google-amp

I'm using [this extension](https://store.plumrocket.com/accelerated-mobile-pages-magento2-extension.html) for creating AMP pages for our Magento e-commerce website.

In that extension, they create different pages for AMP (home page, category page, product page). We felt it is an extra work.

is this possible to convert the current page to AMP? (without any modification)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible without having any modification unless you use some third party apps. You may check this [Convert HTML to AMP](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/tutorials/converting) tutorial. Be noted that it is strongly recommended that you use HTTPS in production environments. HTTPS has several benefits beyond just security including SEO. You can read more about this topic in this [Google Webmaster blog post](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2014/08/https-as-ranking-signal.html). Also, from this [page](http://www.seoblog.com/2016/10/guide-converting-page-amp/), if you use WordPress, all you have to do is download [the official AMP WordPress plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/amp/).